# C++ (E0158 expression must be an lvalue or a function designator) and (Error C2102 '&' requires l-value)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, copy

In my homework I got the task to create a class for prefix_vector so the main work without any modification.

I always run into errors:

> E0158 expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

and

> Error C2102   '&' requires l-value

How could I make this without any compilation error?

```
template <class T>
class prefix_vector
{
public:
    prefix_vector(std::vector <T>& x) :vpre{ x }
    {
    }
    void push_back(const T & t)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vpre.size(); i++)
        {
            if (t == vpre[i])
            {
                vpre.erase(vpre.begin() + i);
            }
        }
        vsuf.push_back(t);
        for (int i = 1; i < vsuf.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vsuf.size() - 1; ++j)
            {
                if (vsuf[j] > vsuf[i]) std::swap(vsuf[j], vsuf[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    T  at(const T &  x)
    {
        std::vector <T> vpresu = vpre;

        for (int i = 0; i < vsuf.size(); i++)
        {
            vpresu.push_back(vsuf[i]);
        }
        return vpresu[x + vsuf.size()];
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return vsuf.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector <T> & vpre;
    std::vector <T> & vsuf;
};


const int max = 1000;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    prefix_vector<int> p(v);
    prefix_vector<int> a(p);
    prefix_vector<int> b(p);
    prefix_vector<int> c(p);

    a.push_back(2);
    b.push_back(4);
    c.push_back(8);
    c.push_back(1);

    std::vector<std::string> s;
    s.push_back("Hello");
    prefix_vector<std::string> sh(s);
    prefix_vector<std::string> sa(sh);
    sa.push_back("World");
    prefix_vector<std::string> sb(sh);


    if (8 == c.at(max) && &(a.at(max / 2)) == &(b.at(max / 2)) &&
        a.size() == b.size() && 1 == p.at(1) && 4 == b.at(max) &&
        &(b.at(max - 1)) == &(c.at(max - 1)) &&
        &(b.at(max)) != &(c.at(max)) && 1 == sb.size() &&
        1 == sh.size() && "Hello" == sa.at(0))
    {
        std::cout << "you did great" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get

> E0158 expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
>
> Error C2102 '&' requires l-value

The output should be:

```
you did great
```

Comment: `T  at(const T &  x)` -> `T& at(std::size_t x)`? Also why do you use `const T &` there if `T` can be `std::string`?

Comment: `std::vector <T> & vsuf` is not iniyialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
E0158 expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

Error   C2102   '&' requires l-value
```

means you are trying to get an address of temporary (in this case r-value) which is illegal. Using `&` on some object means taking its address - so it must exist in memory somewhere. l-values are objects which might be stored in CPU register, so it makes no sense to take its address.

In your case, you try to compare addresses instead of values, so instead of:

```
&(a.at(max / 2)) == &(b.at(max / 2))
^                   ^
```

you should:

```
(a.at(max / 2)) == (b.at(max / 2))
```

After fixing it, you will probably find lots of other bugs, but I suppose you can handle them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`at` it's returning a temporary copy of the object in your vector. You can't get a pointer to a temporary object (or "r-value") so `&(a.at(max / 2))` generates an error.

I'm not sure what you're trying to test but I guess `(a.at(max / 2)!= 0)` is the correct syntax.

Alternatively change `at` to return a reference which you can then get a pointer to.